# Intel Media SDK: Regarding mfxIMPL Usage

Tags: streaming, intel, video-encoding, intel-media-sdk

Please Can someone clarify what is the usage of mfxIMPL datastructure provided by Intel Media SDK?
Decoding sample app has a code line:
`mfxIMPL impl = MFX_IMPL_HARDWARE;`
Does this means the decoder runs on the GPU only.
If I change the MFX_IMPL_HARDWARE to MFX_IMPL_SOFTWARE, will the decoder run on CPU only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Media SDK provides APIs that can be executed on either core (SW implementation), or on the GPU/fixed-function-logic (HW-accelerated Implementation), depending on the system and its capabilities.

"mfxIMPL impl" -> Use software, or hardware or best available implementation. We recommend using MFX_IMPL_HARDWARE, or MFX_IMPL_AUTO if you are unsure of the underlying driver support. If MFX_IMPL_AUTO is specified on a system that does not support HW acceleration, then the SW impl is automatically used as default. Hope this helps.